# How to write an rspec test that interacts with a React form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium-webdriver, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm going to start off by saying I might be going about this the wrong way and I'm open to other ways of testing this.

I have a Rails/React app that I'm trying to add more testing to. I've written rspec tests before that were completely contained to checking things in the backend. Now I'm trying to write a test that checks creating a blog post. I've done this before when the form I was testing was a Rails view, but I've never done this when the form was built in React on the frontend.

This is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.3'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '~> 1.1'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false


# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

# CSS style
gem "bulma-rails", "~> 0.8.0"

# jquery
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Setup Devise
gem 'devise'
gem 'active_model_serializers'

# Install pry for debugging
gem 'pry'

# Sendgrid/Contact form
gem 'sendgrid-ruby'
gem 'mail_form'

# Env variable management
gem 'figaro', '~> 1.2'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 6.2'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.2'
  gem 'faker', '~> 2.18'
  gem 'launchy'
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 3.35', '>= 3.35.3'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end
```

This is my test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'user signs in', %Q{
  As an admin user
  I want to create new posts
  when I am signed in
} do

  scenario 'admin creates new blog post', js: true do
    user = FactoryBot.create(:user_1)
    post = FactoryBot.create(:post_1)
    visit '/post/new'
    
    # binding.pry
    fill_in 'title', with: post.title
    fill_in 'body', with: post.body
    fill_in 'image', with: post.image
    fill_in 'keywords', with: post.keywords
    binding.pry

    click_button 'Submit'
    binding.pry
    expect(page).to have_content(post.title)
  end

end
```

I've been using `binding.pry` and `save_and_open_page` to try and figure out what's going on. The gets to `/post/new` and fills out the form correctly. So that parts working. But when it clicks on `Submit`, this error occurs:

```
[1] pry(#<RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserSignsInAsAnAdminUserIWantToCreateNewPostsWhenIAmSignedIn>)> 2021-08-20 13:51:45 -0400 Rack app ("GET /" - (127.0.0.1)): #<ActionController::UnknownFormat: HomepagesController#index is missing a template for this request format and variant.

request.formats: ["application/json"]
request.variant: []>
```

I'm not exactly sure what's happening here. I'm guessing I'm missing some part of the config to get the JS aspect of this test to work? Also just to note, this form does work in development/production. The data from the form should be going to the Posts Controller.

Alternative option to getting this to work. Would it make more sense to write response tests for backend stuff. And then just Jest or another library to test frontend functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Your form is submitting, but you do not have the correct format in your Home controller. In the index method, you should add how you want the controller to handle js format.

Can you make sure that your method handles both html and json like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.json { render json: @whatever_you_want_to_return }
end
```

As for testing, your test is good, but you should always test all parts of your application to make sure they return what you intend them to.